# Error en mi ruta "/" en localhost de Laravel. 404 Not Found nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu) y Permission denied

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx, localhost

Estoy corriendo mi aplicación de Laravel en Ubuntu y cuando quiero accesar a la ruta "/" me dice que mi página no se encontró. Estoy en localhost.

`404 Not Found nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)`

Los logs actualmente me muestran este error:

```
2024/02/28 09:16:33 [crit] 4279#4279: *2 stat() "/root/sickofmetal/public/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"
```

Pasos para iniciar mi servidor son los siguientes.

- Uso Docker entonces empiezo abriendo Docker desktop.
- Una vez que el contenedor esta corriendo, abro vscode y en la terminal ingreso al contenedor como usuario "root."
- Después inicio vite de la siguiente manera: `npm run dev`

Actualmente, checando el navegador me sale el mensaje de 404.

Esta es la configuración que tengo para el servidor, el archivo "/etc/nginx/sites-available/default":

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

        root /sickofmetal/public;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

El comando `sudo nginx -t` me dice que no hay error de sintaxis y también tengo un symlink creado en sites-enabled. Cuando reinicio nginx el problema sigue.

He intentado utilizar mi IP en el bloque del servidor, por ejemplo:

```
server {
       listen 80;
       listen 10x.32.22.xx;
}
```

Pero no funciona. Esto tengo dentro de la configuración de nginx

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Según el error del log que puse al principio, el permiso para leer el archivo "index.php" no es permitido, fue denegado. Checando los permisos me sale lo siguiente:

`4 -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data root 1710 Jun 19  2023 sickofmetal/public/index.php`

Intente cambiar los permisos a ese archivo de esta manera: `chmod 644 sickofmetal/public/index.php` reiniciando el servidor, pero el problema persiste.

Me gustaría saber cómo debería de tener asignados los permisos para poder accesar "index.php" desde mi navegador.

Comment: No guardes cosas de la app en `/root/..` , ahi no deberia acceder ningun servidor web por seguridad, no es cuestion de cambiar permisos si no de mover ese directorio a otro lado, como `/var/..` o algo asi. De todas formas, revisa que los directorios padres tambien pueda acceder, y me parece que deberia de tener permisos de ejecucion tambien el apache

Comment: Si, muchas gracias. De echo así lo resolví, de esa manera. Tuve que reconstruir el proyecto empezando por cambiar la ruta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví cambiando la ruta del proyecto a "var/www/html." El proyecto tuvo que reiniciarse. Se reconstruyó la imagen de Docker, el código en git, las migraciones, etc.

Después resolví los permisos que estaban pendientes y listo.